# Panda's : Matrix from pd.crosstab()

Tags: python, pandas

I'm progressively learning pandas, I figured out that `pd.crosstab()` can do marvels but I've hard time to make it work in that case.

I have a list of objects `obj` tagged with an int, I want to have the matrix of the objects sharing the same tag (1 if it's the same, 0 else)

```
| obj | tag |
|-----|-----|
| a   | 0   |
| b   | 2   |
| c   | 1   |
| ... | ... |
| z   | 2   |
```

->

```
|     | a | b | c | ... | z |
|-----|---|---|---|-----|---|
| a   | 1 | 0 | 0 | .   | 0 |
| b   | 0 | 1 | 0 | .   | 1 |
| c   | 0 | 0 | 1 | .   | 0 |
| ... | . | . | . | .   | 0 |
| z   | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0   | 1 |
```

There are some `for`midables ways to do it, is there one more panda-friendly ?

PS : Tried with `pd.crosstab(df.obj, df.obj, values=df.tag, aggfunc=[np.sum])` but NaN filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) and [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = df.merge(df, on='tag')
df = pd.crosstab(df.obj_x, df.obj_y).rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
   a  b  c  z
a  1  0  0  0
b  0  1  0  1
c  0  0  1  0
z  0  1  0  1
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael ! That did the trick. I'll keep in mind the merge func